# iOS 8.1 killed a part of my webview. Help wanted

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

I updated to iOS 8.1 and updated my xcode but now something is broken on with my webview.

I used this part of code:

```
let stream = "http://stream.hive365.co.uk:8088/live"
    let url  = NSURL(string: stream)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webplayer.loadRequest(request)
```

xcode gives a error about the let request

> value of optional type NSURL? not unwrapped; did you mean to use! or ?

I'm new with iOS swift development and can't get the error away...

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURL returns an [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496) so you need to check if it is `nil`

```
let stream = "http://stream.hive365.co.uk:8088/live"
if let url  = NSURL(string: stream) {
  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
  webplayer.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Thank. the error is gone only I'm getting a new fun error and I get stuck in the loading screen.. `dyld: Symbol not found: _swift_isaMask
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E155A449-DA43-435D-9874-93D73D9AA1F7/hive365.app/hive365
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E155A449-DA43-435D-9874-93D73D9AA1F7/hive365.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E155A449-DA43-435D-9874-93D73D9AA1F7/hive365.app/hive365
(lldb) `

Comment: Thats a completely different question, try clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

change
`let url  = NSURL(string: stream)`
to
`let url  = NSURL(string: stream)?`
or
`let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: stream) as NSURL`

Comment: Neither of those will work. Give it a try in Playgrounds. FYI `let url = NSURL(string: stream)!`